# .Net Regex ValidationExpression ASCII

Tags: .net, regex, ascii

Anyone know a good Regex expression to drop in the ValidationExpression to be sure that my users are only entering ASCII characters?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="myRegex" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationExpression="???" ErrorMessage="Non-ASCII Characters" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: Do you mean just alpha-numeric or the full range of ASCII characters?

Comment: Full Range Please.. avoiding things like.. ø

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you may want to watch out for is the lower part of the ASCII table has a lot of control characters which can cause funky results.  Here's the expression I use to only allow "non-funky" characters:

```
^([^\x0d\x0a\x20-\x7e\t]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map the possible 0x00 - 0xff ASCII values you can use this regular expression (.NET).

```
^([\x00-\xff]*)$
```