# Verifying that an uploaded file contains only plain text

Tags: c#, text, string

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that allows the user to upload a file that should only contain plain text.

I am looking for a simple approach to validate that the file does indeed contain only text.

For my purposes I am happy to define *text* as *any of the characters that I can see printed on my GB QWERTY keyboard*.

Business rules mean that my uploaded file won't contain any accented characters, so it doesn't matter if the code accepts or rejects these.

Approaches so far that have not worked:

- Checking the content-type; no good as this is dependant on the file extension
- Checking `char.IsControl` for each character; no good as the file can contain pipe (|) characters which are considered to be control characters

I'd rather avoid using a lengthy `Regex` pattern to get this to work.

Comment: It seems like the encoding of the text file is relevant here, too, unless you're mandating that you are dealing with single-byte characters.

Comment: Have you considered scanning the data with a regular expression?

Comment: how do you define "plain text"? what may be contained in plain text and what not?

Comment: Does language come into picture? What is 'plain text' in chinese is gibberish in english. And perhaps you can post a picture of your keyboard? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want [ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) 32-126 plus a few odds and ends like 9 (horizontal tab), carriage return & linefeed, etc..

> I'd rather avoid using a lengthy Regex
>   pattern to get this to work.

As long as that doesn't mean 'no regular expressions at all', you can use the accepted answer from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150901/net-regex-validationexpression-ascii) (I've added the horizontal tab character to the original):

```
^([^\x09\x0d\x0a\x20-\x7e\t]*)$
```